# Can product of two matrices be an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

**Preamble**-My knowledge of advanced algebra is very limited, I would appreciate your patience if I misuse the notation. I have tried my best to use the correct notation. In any case, I will be more than happy to edit the question if the mistakes are pointed out to me.

**Question**- I have two linear transformations $A:\mathcal{V}\rightarrow\mathcal{W}$, and $B:\mathcal{W}\rightarrow\mathcal{V}$, where $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{W}$ are finite vector spaces over the Filed of real numbers. Then the question is can their product matrix $T=BA$, be an isomorphism?

If $T=BA$ can be an isomorphism what properties should $A$ and $B$ hold?

Comment: Hint: Yes, it can be an isomorphism.  Can you think of some examples?

Comment: Thanks. I can only think of one example and that being $A:\mathcal{V}\rightarrow\mathcal{W}$ and $B$ being Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$, i.e. $B=(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$, where $(\cdot)^T$ means matrix transpose. But I cannot seem to be able to generalize this in terms of properties that $A$ and $B$ should hold.

Comment: If $W$ has smaller dimension than $V$ then $BA$ can't be an isomorphism.

Comment: @user25959 Thanks! is there also an if and only if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very quick example would be: if $A:V \rightarrow W$ is an invertible linear transformation, then choose $B = A^{-1}:W \rightarrow V$. Their product is then just the identity matrix on $V$, i.e. $T = BA = \text{Id}_{V}$.

More generally, the product matrix $T: V \rightarrow V$ needs to be bijective, and $\mathbb{R}$-linear (since we are dealing with real vector spaces), so
$$T(\alpha v + \beta w) = \alpha T(v) + \beta T(w),\qquad \text{for all }\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R},\ \text{for all }v,w \in V.$$
Now bijectivity of $T$ is equivalent to it being invertible and as it is the product of two matrices, we have that $T^{-1} = (BA)^{-1} = A^{-1}B^{-1}$, so both $A$ and $B$ need to be invertible as well, or equivalently again that $A$ and $B$ need to both be bijective.

Comment: Thanks! What happens if for non-square matrices $T=BA$, where $B=(A{^\dagger} A)^{-1}A^{\dagger}$, $(\cdot)^{\dagger}$ being transpose operation, is $T$ still isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, since even if say $A:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ with $n \neq m$, the product $A^{T}A$ is a square matrix as $A^{T}:\mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then $T = BA = (A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T} \circ A = (A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}A = \text{I}_{n}$. So in that case $T$ is just the identity matrix.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I now know that if $A$ and $B$ are square then they need to be invertible . But what properties the non-square matrices should hold ? What conditions $BA=I$ imposes on $B$ and $A$ for non-square matrices? For example, conditions on the dimension of image or Kernel $A$ and $B$.

Comment: So if $A:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $B:\mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$, for $A$ to have a left-inverse we need that $\text{rank}(A) = n$ so that it is bijective onto a subspace $\text{im}(A) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}$, so in particular we need $m \geq n$. Conversely, if $B$ has $\text{rank}(B) = m$, then there exists a right-inverse to it.